# Alternatives to boxing string field or extending ALL strings in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, extension-methods, boxing

Given that one can't subclass builtin types in Kotlin, I'm looking for a way to add special method functionality to **specific types of string fields** in a record, without applying those extension functions to **all strings** (even within that record type).  Say, for example, I have some mutable string fields inside a record, for which I want to define special purpose behaviors.

```
class Customer {
  // ...
  var zipcode: String
  var email: String
  // ...
}
```

- For `zipcode`, assume I'd like to be able to call
  `thisCustomer.zipcode.plusFour` to get the +4 of the zip code (99999-**9999**) via regex.
- For `email`, assume I'd like to be able to call
  `thisCustomer.email.domain` to have a regex go get the ...@**company.com**
  portion of the specified email.

My objectives are to:

1. Avoid the runtime overhead of boxing `zipcode` into a `class Zipcode` with just a 
   single var inside, given that the size of the Customer recordset could potentailly be millions.
2. Avoid the syntax of having to assign 
       `thisCustomer.zipcode.value = "99999-9999"` or `thisCustomer.zipcode = Zipcode("99999-9999")`, if I did end up having to box the string.
3. Avoid adding general `String.plusFour` and
       `String.domain` extension properties, even just within the Customer
       class... because zipcodes and emails could technically call each others'
       extensions

I've been thinking this over and considered the following options, but struck out with each:

- subclassing String:  *Not possible since strings (and all built-ins)
  are closed*
- applying an interface Zip to the var declaration (`var zipcode:
  String, Zip`):  *No such syntax I could find*
- adding inner functions within the getter itself:  *Syntax doesn't seem to exist for this*
- using objects or functions-within-functions:  *Couldn't think of a way
  for this to work, although I might not be imaginative enough*

Am I missing an obvious solution here?  Even if not obvious, with all the syntactic magic of Kotlin, is there a way to make it happen?  Maybe there's a way to accomplish some/all of the objectives above without using any of these approaches?

Comment: Are you against making these functions of Customer instead of this string subtype you want? Have a `Customer.zipCodePlusFour` and a `Customer.emailDomain`?

Comment: That's the backup plan, because I hate the idea of boxing just for this.  Because this is a simplified example, it doesn't show that there are many fields of each string "subtype" which would ideally inherit the same functionality.  However, even with your suggestion, I could just have a master function for each subtype's behavior that takes a parameter to indicate which var it is to operate on.

Comment: Yea I agree with the anti-boxing sentiment. Have you also considered perhaps going the extension method route, but returning a nullable/option type so that the extension method could null/None if it wasn't a valid string to begin with? That may end up being more overhead than the boxing though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [type aliases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html) to make the intention clear:

```
typealias ZipCode = String
val ZipCode.plusFour get() = ...

typealias Email = String
val Email.domain get() = ...

class Customer {
  // ...
  var zipcode: ZipCode
  var email: Email
  // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this *only* clarifies intentions and doesn't stop the compiler from allowing `zipcode.domain`. But for now I don't think there is any way which satisfies both objectives 1 and 3.

Kotlin developers have decided not to support assignment-incompatible type aliases, which would have fit all your requirements, in favor of waiting for value classes to be available on JVM, as discussed in https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/4.

Comment: This is a good fallback as well, but as you say, would be better if/when assignment-incompatible type aliases worked.  I'm going to tinker with delegates a bit more, and if it leads nowhere, then I'm coming back to your `typealias` idea.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a decorator class using delegate:

```
class YourString(val value: String) : Comparable<String> by value, CharSequence by value {

    val plusFour: String
        get() = ""  //your logic here

    val domain: String
        get() = ""  //your logic here

    override fun toString() = value
}
```

Usage:

```
fun String.toYourString() = YourString(this)

class Customer(var zipCode: YourString, var email: YourString)

val customer = Customer("+4 99999-9999".toYourString(), "xxx@company.com".toYourString())
println(customer.zipCode.plusFour)
println(customer.email.domain)
```

Comment: Implementing `Comparable<String>` for a class that is not a subclass of type `String` doesn't make sense. While you can call `YourString.compareTo(String)`, it will be impossible to call `String.compareTo(YourString)` or `YourString.compareTo(YourString)`.

Comment: This fails objective 1.

Comment: This is interesting, but as Alexey mentions, it doesn't fully avoid the overhead and the referential ugliness of applying the lipstick to the pig (and/or its values).  However, you've set me thinking about delegates, both class- and property-type.  I'm looking into the source code implementations of `lazy` and others to see if I can get any ideas.  I'm wondering if the 1.1 addition of `provideDelegate` might provide the necessary place to slip in the syntactic magic.  More to come... or if anyone has thoughts... I'm still interested.